# Ошибка генератора python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = ((input().replace(",", " ")).replace(";", " ")).split()
print(int(i) for i in a if int(i) > 999999999)
```

При таком инпуте:

```
10000,10000000000,200000;2000000000,1345678910,330000000
```

выдает ошибку

> ```
> (<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0129ABB0>)
> ```

Действия программы:
Программа выводит на экран только те числа, которые больше одного миллиарда.
Когда выполнял программу в много строчек, все работало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не ошибка генератора. Скрипт честно выдает вам ссылку на объект-генератор. Вам просто нужно обернуть его в список, например.

```
b='10000,10000000000,200000;2000000000,1345678910,330000000'
a = ((b.replace(",", " ")).replace(";", " ")).split()
print([int(i) for i in a if int(i) > 999999999])
```

выдаст:

```
[10000000000, 2000000000, 1345678910]
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли

Answer (score 1):

```
[print(int(i)) for i in a if int(i) > 999999999]
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 10000000000
> 2000000000
> 1345678910
> ```

---

Объяснение:

`print()` - функция, которая всегда возвращает `None`, но мы *не используем* это значение, а только *побочный эффект* функции `print()` - вывод её параметра.

И так, самую *абстракцию списка (list comprehension)* -  `[.....]`  - мы *не применяем именно для создания списка самого* (мы его *не сохраняем ни в какой переменной*), а только для побочного эффекта функции `print()`.